# Hyperledger composer on hyperledger fabric deployed on Docker swarm

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed a one org hyperledger fabric network over docker swarm. Where one node has an orderer, peer , ca and couchdb and other node has one couchdb and node. I was able to invoke basic chaincode over it. Now I want to deploy composer over it. But I am not sure what shall I give in request and event url of connection.json. I already tried giving individual IPs instead of localhost,but no luck. I used this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) to deploy one org fabric network over docker swarm.

Answer (score 0):

See https://discourse.skcript.com/t/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/602

you will need the requestURL and eventURL definition, along with peer addresses from the other 'node' (I assume you mean 'machine') on your node 1.